# Promise.map returning a broken object

Tags: javascript, bluebird

i'm using the Promise.map to make some operations in an array of objects, which object represents a file.

Inside i'm mapping this files, and when i finish, i want return a object just like this:

```
{
  output: {
    order_by: 'Competência',
    output_data: 'TEST.dados.csv',
    output_result: 'TEST.resultado.csv'
  },
  files: [{
    full_name: 'Relat¢rio RE (1) 02.2014.pdf',
    mime: 'application/pdf',
    pages: [],
    status: [],
    text: ''
  }, {
    exists: false,
    extension: 'pdf',
    full_name: 'Relat¢rio RE (1) 02.2014.pdf',
    mime: 'application/pdf',
    pages: [],
    status: [],
    text: ''
  }]
}
```

And when i use my code like this:

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  return Promise.map(files, function(file) {
    var map;
    result.push(mapping_files(file));
    if (result.length === files.length) {
      map = {
        output: mapping_output(output),
        files: result
      };
      return resolve(map);
    }
  }, {
    concurrency: 3000
  });
});
```

With resolve, reject.. the output will be PERFECT.. but if i delete the new Promise:

```
return Promise.map(files, function(file) {
  var map;
  result.push(mapping_files(file));
  if (result.length === files.length) {
    return map = {
      output: mapping_output(output),
      files: result
    };
  }
}, {
  concurrency: 3000
});
```

The output will be like this:

```
[undefined, {
  output: {
    order_by: 'Competência',
    output_data: 'TEST.dados.csv',
    output_result: 'TEST.resultado.csv'
  },
  files: [
    [Object],
    [Object]
  ]
}]
```

Why this? I MUST return an array when i'm using the Promise.map?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this functionality, so I won't add this as an answer, but I think you're misunderstanding `map`. It just maps from an array of inputs to an array of outputs of the same length. So, if you don't return something for an input, you'll get `undefined`. It's possible that you're really looking for [`reduce`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.reduce.html), which allows you to selectively add something to the output.

Comment: The problem with reduce is that i can't use the concurrency @DerekPeterson

Comment: @JoãoCalvin - you talk about concurrency, but your processing of your files does not show any async operation.  It looks to me like you could just use normal synchronous `.reduce()`.  If `mapping_files()` or `mapping_output()` are async, then they won't work the way you're using them because you're using the synchronously.

Comment: FYI, I answered your [more recent other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33507878/how-to-use-bluebird-map-and-return-object) which shows how to return an object from `Promise.map()`.